# Rigorous proof about homothetic figures

Tags: geometry

Take a point $P$ in the 2D plane. If you're given two line segments $AB$ and $CD$ such that $PM$ and $PN$ are perpendicular bisectors where $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $AB$ and $CD$ (respectively). 
This doesn't mean that they are homothetic. They can or can not be rotationally homothetic.

But when it's mentioned that $AC=BD$, they tend to become rotationally homothetic .

Can I get a rigorous proof?
I can't prove it with similarity. 
This is not any problem. I am trying to understand the reason behind this. Just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that there's a rotational homothety *centered at $P$* taking $AB$ to $CD$, we'll let $O$ be the center of the unique rotational homothety taking $AB$ to $CD$ (which almost always exists), and prove $O=P$.

A key fact about rotational homothety is that in this setting, there is always a second rotational homothety, also centered at $O$, which takes $AC$ to $BD$. But $AC = BD$. So this second rotational homothety is in fact just a rotation. This means that $A$ and $B$ lie on a circle centered at $O$, and $C$ and $D$ lie on another circle centered at $O$.

But then the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$ are perpendicular bisectors of chords in circles with center $O$. So they both pass through $O$. Almost always the two perpendicular bisectors have a unique intersection point. But we are told that $PM$ and $PN$ are perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$. So $O=P$, and we are done.

---

The question says "When it's mentioned that $AC=BD$ they tend to become rotationally homothetic" I assume for the same reason that I said "almost always" twice in the proof above: this doesn't always work. There are two exceptional cases.

First, it's possible that there is no rotational homothety taking $AB$ to $CD$. This happens when $ABDC$ is a parallelogram (so this case does satisfy $AC = BD$).

Second, it's possible that the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$ and $CD$ coincide. In that case, just because $O$ lies on both and $P$ also lies on both doesn't mean that $O=P$. In this case, there are many candidate points for $P$, but only one of them is the center of a rotational homothety (actually, just a homothety) taking $AB$ to $CD$.

Comment: Yeah thanks. It's true that they tend to be homothetic. Not always. It's not any question. Just came to my mind and I couldn't prove. Silly of me. Well, are you the same Misha of AoPS?

Comment: Um... yes, in that I have the account named "Misha" on AoPS; no, in that I've only posted there twice, which was twelve years ago, so I'm probably not the person you're thinking of?